# C casting char pointer to int or short pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, interpreter

I'm working on a simple interpreter(a subset of Basic.) The source would be in memory as an array of strings. I would like to keep it simple so not going to consider bytecode. The execution will start by parsing the whole program to check for syntax errors and setup few data structures to manage loops and GOTO jump addresses then start a function to process it line by line from the source. To speedup execution, I want to convert number literals in the source to their binary representation. What is the correct way to do that in C? Is casting char pointer to int or short pointer a bad idea? What other steps I can take to improve performance? The target is x86?

Comment: Casting isn't going to help at all. You need to convert the char value to an int value - using atoi or similar. The normal way to approach a problem like this is to start with a tokenizer - don't store the source as strings, read it and convert it to a list of tokens. One of the tokens will be something like "literal_number"

Comment: Have you considered using C++, Rust, Golang etc.? Those can greatly facilitate your task, if they are viable (e.g., Golang has garbage collection, which may or may not be an issue). Also, consider transpiling your language to C or another language. If it must be an interpreter in C, a simple search for ```c string to int``` yields numerous answers to the question.

Comment: The problem is: numbers in text and their binary representation differ pretty much, that starts already with single digits: A `7` in text is represented by an ASCII value of 55 (0x37). A number like `77` needs two bytes in text but can be represented in one single byte (e.g. as `unsigned char`) as binary number – and much more...

Comment: Thanks all, I forgot to mention that I defined tokens already. I'm using 0x80 and up as tokens for example 0x81 is number-token which would be followed by the value of the number.  What I want is how to store the value after the 0x81 token type. What about something like  *(int*) &(p+1)... giving that p points to where 0x81 is stored?

Comment: `(int)&(p + 1)` is complete non-sense (sorry), `p+1` gives a temporary you cannot even take the address of... Sorry to need to tell you: There's no way around *parsing* the number literal – though luckily there are a bunch of functions for, e.g. `strtoll` (but you might yet need to have an eye on too long literals!).

Comment: @Aconcagua
What about ?  p++;  star(int star) p = strtoll (str, NULL, 10); first the pointer advanced beyond the 0x81 num-token) then the number where str pointing is converted to int and stored right after 0x81

Comment: @user3479526 What is `star(int star)`??

Comment: At first: `strtoll` returns a *`long long`*, so you would potentially cut away some relevant bytes. Then you might not have enough space to write the converted number back to the string, e.g. `"7"` occupies just one single byte (not considering the terminating null character), but `long long` requires eight of. You'd overwrite subsequent parts of the string (or at the end potentially write beyond). Finally the pointer you want to write to might be misaligned (-> undefined behaviour!).

Comment: Do not modify the input string (even if it *did* work, handling that *will* get a pain), instead, as @John3136 denoted already, create a list of *tokens*. You could write an `enum` containing identifiers for every type of tokens, and a struct containing the token data. That would comprise exactly that enum and a union containing the tokens specific data (if need be), e.g. for the number literal token its value, for a string literal the string content, etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `*(int*)` – she/he apparently is not aware of `\*` or the back-ticks.

Comment: @Aconcagua
"Finally the pointer you want to write to might be misaligned (-> undefined behaviour!)" That is the main point of my question, however I read somewhere that in x86 it's ok for a pointer to not be aligned. Am I correct. Actually, I refrained from going the token struct way because I want keep the source like BASIC does (convert source to internal form which it's easy  to recover the source)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `BASIC` doesn't do so by modifying input strings either. If you want to recover the original source 1:1 you might, though, have to store additional information, e.g. for a `WHITE_SPACE` token you might need to store the substring comprising the entire whitespace section (several spaces, tabs, newlines, etc).

Comment: Indeed, X86 *can* do misaligned data reads; still this is generally avoided as it can have performance impacts (potentially two cache misses instead of a single one, etc). It is the *standard* that specifies the behaviour as undefined, but sometimes compiler provide *extensions* making it well defined again (like e.g. GCC and others introducing type punning via unions in C++, UB in general there is same issue as in C). Relying on these you produce *non-portable* code, though (what, if you happen to decide to port your interpreter to ARM-linux or ARM-windows???).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I guess I'd consider converting source to bytecode however I tested the execution of 2 nested  while loops calculating the prime numbers less than 10000 it did it in 3.5s. A similar program in C took .06s so it's 60 times slower but guess not too bad giving my naïve implementation and lack of sound knowledge in CS . By the way check this about BASIC internal program files http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~af380/GW-BASIC-tokens.html

Comment: Regarding the data alignment issue, how bytecode implementations deal with that when opcode comes with multi byte arguments? How is it possible to keep alignment given that the code to be executed is arbitrary?

Comment: @user3479526 Padding bytes… Assuming you have some base address to memory (e. g. stack pointer), you simply add (or subtract -> top-down stack) sufficient bytes such that you get an aligned address. Subtracting in this case is a bit simpler, you just need to mask out those bits that might violate alignment (e.g. the last 3 ones for 8- byte-alignment) without any special treatment differentiating between unaligned and already aligned addresses (or not caring and instead wasting memory on aligned) which probably is the (or one) reason why top-down-stacks are more common in operating systems.